# ¿Como validar varios txt vacios?

Tags: c#, formularios, validación

Hola soy estudiante y tengo el siguiente problema.
Estoy desarrollando un formulario en C# y quisiera evitar que algunos txt estén vacíos, he leído que esta es una forma de hacerlo:

```
if (this.txt.Text.Equals(""))
    {
        Response.Write("El campo  esta vacio");
    }
```

Pero resulta que tengo varios txt, hay alguna forma de validar que no estén vacíos sin usar tantos if, u obligado tendré que hacerlo. Gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te explicaré más o menos como seria en palabras castellanas ya que también soy estudiante y todavía no he trabajado con C# pero ya pasé por esta cuestión. lo he hecho en VB. en primer lugar lo debes programar en el botón "registrar" (Veo tu imagen), con el evento "clic". Pones el condicional "if" y preguntas Textbox == "" (textbox es igual a vacío?) entonces ya te mostraría las instrucciones que le indicas que sería " este campo está vacío. Espero logres comprenderme.

Comment: Si se que código debo usar, arriba puse el ejemplo, mi duda es si debo si o si usar un if por cada txt porque ademas de los que aparecen en la imagen hay mas txt en la otra pestaña. Quiero saber si hay alguna otra posibilidad o si obligado tendré que usar un if por cada txt

Comment: La respuesta es si. no hay otra forma que no implique una sobrecarga en la funcionalidad del sistema.

Answer (score 1):

podrías recorrer los controles que tenes en tu formulario, preguntar si ese control es del tipo Text y ahí controlar si esta vació o no.
No estoy con el Visual Studio instalado para probar el código que te paso, pero esa es la lógica que yo usaba.

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls){
if (c is TextBox){
    TextBox textBox = c as TextBox;
    if (textBox.Text == string.Empty){
         Response.Write("El campo  esta vacio");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Esto funciona barbaro.. ojala realmente ninguno tenga que estar vacio, porque en ese caso tenes que ponerte a mirar nombres y es un lio.